# Calculate no: of girls and boys of particular weight catagory.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\text{Weight} & \text{Boys} & \text{Girls} \\ \hline
40 & \dfrac{a+35}{3} & \dfrac{a+35}{4}\\ \hline
44 & a & a \\ \hline
46 & b & b \\ \hline
50 & a+35 & \dfrac{a+35}{3} \\ \hline
\text{total} & 297 & 243 \\ \hline
\end{array}$

I drew the table considering $a=44\ \ $ kg girls and $b=46\ \ $kg girls.

and by calculating I got [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cdfrac%7Ba%2B35%7D%7B3%7D%2Ba%2B35%2Bb%2Ba%3D297,+++%5Cdfrac%7Ba%2B35%7D%7B4%7D%2Ba%2Bb%2B35%2B%5Cdfrac%7Ba%2B35%7D%7B3%7D%3D243,%5Cdfrac%7Ba%2B35%7D%7B3%7D%3Dx,%5Cdfrac%7Ba%2B35%7D%7B4%7D%3Dy)

while the answer given in book are different as follows,

$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
 \text{que no} & \text{correct option} \\ \hline
15 & b \\ \hline
16 & a \\ \hline
17 & b \\ \hline
18 & a \\ \hline
19 & b \\ \hline
20 & a \\ \hline
\end{array}$

I look for a short and simple way. I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: Since the number of $44$ kg girls is equal to the number of $46$  boys, the number of $46$ kg boys should be $a$.  Since the number of $46$ kg girls is equal to the number of $44$ kg boys, the number of $44$ kg boys should be $b$.

Comment: The problem is poorly stated in that there is nothing saying all weights of boys and girls have been covered. I.e, that there are not girls who weigh 48 kg or boys weighing 42 kg. It seems obvious that they want you to assume this (as you have), so I wouldn't about it. But whoever *wrote* this problem deserves a dope slap. If they are teaching mathematics, they have no excuse for being so sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

Let $G$ be the total number of girls and $B$ the total number of boys. We are first given two facts about these totals (it is reasonable to assume no hermaphrodites are intended):
$$G + B = 540$$
$$\frac GB = \frac9{11}$$
Thus we can replace $G$ in the first equation with $\frac{9B}{11}$:
$$\frac{9B}{11} + B = 540\\
\frac{20B}{11} = 540\\
B = \frac{11}{20}540 = 297$$
$$G = 540 - 297 = 243$$
There. That alone will simplify some of the math. There are 297 boys and 243 girls.

Now let's do something probably different than you've been taught and likely to be a bit frightening at first, but it is often a good way to see relationships and make sure you have them right. We will very quickly discard the extra baggage, though, so don't let it bother you.

Assign a separate variable to each of the unknowns. You want to make them recognizable, so you immediately know which is which, so we are not going to name them $a, b, c, ...$. Instead, we'll use "$g$" for girls and "$b$" for boys, and subscripts for the weight. But I'm lazy and don't see any reason to lug around a digit that isn't doing any work, so I'm dropping the leading $4$. Alas, that still leaves $50$, but we'll just use $a$ instead (not arbitrary! - $A$ is $10$ in hexadecimal). So we have:
$$\begin{array}{r|c|c} & \text{Girls} & \text{Boys}\\\hline
40 \text{ kg} & g_0 & b_0\\\hline
44 \text{ kg} & g_4 & b_4\\\hline
46 \text{ kg} & g_6 & b_6\\\hline
50 \text{ kg} & g_a & b_a\end{array}$$
Now, the relations given are:$$g_4 = b_6\\b_0=g_a\\b_a=g_4 + 35\\b_4 = g_6\\\frac{b_0}{g_0} = \frac43\\\frac{g_a}{b_a} = \frac13$$
Those last two can be simplified to $$3b_0 = 4g_0\\3g_a = b_a$$
Last time we eliminated the girls and worked with the boys, so to be fair, we should do it the other way now. Start with the obvious substitutions:
$$\begin{array}{r|c|c} & \text{Girls} & \text{Boys}\\\hline
40 \text{ kg} & g_0 & g_a\\\hline
44 \text{ kg} & g_4 & g_6\\\hline
46 \text{ kg} & g_6 & g_4\\\hline
50 \text{ kg} & g_a & g_4+35\end{array}\\
3g_a = 4g_0\\3g_a = g_4+35$$
which gives $$g_a = \frac43g_0\\g_4 = 4g_0 - 35$$
and so
$$\begin{array}{r|c|c} & \text{Girls} & \text{Boys}\\\hline
40 \text{ kg} & g_0 & \frac43g_0\\\hline
44 \text{ kg} & 4g_0 - 35 & g_6\\\hline
46 \text{ kg} & g_6 & 4g_0 - 35\\\hline
50 \text{ kg} & \frac43g_0 & 4g_0\end{array}$$
Now, there are two other equations to use: total girls $= 243$, total boys $= 297$. This gives:

- Girls:$$(g_0) + (4g_0 - 35) + (g_6) + \left(\frac43g_0\right) = 243\\
  \frac{19}3g_0+g_6 = 243 + 35 = 278$$
- Boys:$$\left(\frac43g_0\right) + (g_6) + (4g_0 - 35) + (4g_0) = 297\\
  \frac{28}3g_0 + g_6 = 297 + 35 = 332$$
  Subtracting the Girl equation from the Boy equation (insert entendre here),
  $$\frac93g_0 = 54\\g_0 = 18$$
  Plugging that into either of the two equations gives $$g_6 = 164.$$ Filling out the rest of the table:
  $$\begin{array}{r|c|c} & \text{Girls} & \text{Boys}\\\hline
  40 \text{ kg} & 18 & 24\\\hline
  44 \text{ kg} & 37 & 164\\\hline
  46 \text{ kg} & 164 & 37\\\hline
  50 \text{ kg} & 24 & 72\end{array}$$
  from which we can also deduce with some surety that these are late adolescents or early teens.